# React blank page after deployment in a folder

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react application : http://we****.com/buzz/

The url above shows that its been deployed under `buzz` folder.

It only `displays blank page` and `no console error` in the browser.

I have already set `homepage` variable in package.json and all URLs seems to be fine.

Can someone please let me know the issue.

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "buzz",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "homepage": "http://we****.com/buzz/",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My route file ::

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import HomeComponent from '../Components/Home';
import LoginComponent from '../Components/Login';
import SignupComponent from '../Components/Signup';
import MyStoriesComponent from '../Components/Story/MyStories';
import AddStoryComponent from '../Components/Story/AddStory';

export default class Routes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent} />
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
                    <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignupComponent} />
                    <Route exact path="/mystories" component={MyStoriesComponent} />
                    <Route exact path="/addstory" component={AddStoryComponent} />
                    {/*<Route exact path="/listPartnerAccount/:id" component={ListPartnerAccount} />*/}
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, You need to provide more information including your code in order to get into the details of your issue and find a resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing 2 things:

1) Set following code in package.json file

```
"homepage": "http://we****.com/buzz/"
```

2) Setting the basename in the BrowserRouter in route file:

```
export default class Routes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename={'/buzz'}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent} />
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
                    <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignupComponent} />
                    <Route exact path="/mystories" component={MyStoriesComponent} />
                    <Route exact path="/addstory" component={AddStoryComponent} />
                    {/*<Route exact path="/listPartnerAccount/:id" component={ListPartnerAccount} />*/}
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Please note only setting homepage in package.json file did not work for me, it was the combination of above 2 steps that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

this should working fine if you upload your build files to that directory (http://*****.com/buzz/).

Please confirm first that after added homepage on package.json you build your app. The command is ( yarn run build OR yarn build ), after that upload files from build directory to your desired location.